# How to find items from an array and add them into a list (Java)

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have three simple classes and I want to read from a List to find out how many books are there and how many are being used. Then return a list of all AudioBooks that are currently not being used.

Book:

```
public class Book {
    public String name;
    private String owner;
    public boolean isUsed;
}
```

AudioBook:

```
public class AudioBook extends Book {
    private int totalQTY;
    public int neededQTY;
}
```

And a third class for managing them:

```
public class Manage{
    List<AudioBook> myAudioBooks;
    Stack<Book> shelf;
    int shelfSize = 20;
}
```

My first question is, how do I check, for each item how many are there and how many are being used? And second question is, how do I add the not used items in myList? I tried this:

```
public List<Book> findNotUsedBooks(){

    //get totalQTY of each book and add them to a list
    for(int i = 0; i < myAudioBooks.size(); i++){
        List<Integer> myList = myAudioBooks.get(i).getQTY();
    }

    List<Book> myList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for(AudioBook a : myAudioBooks){

    //this wouldn't work because getQTY() returns an int
    myList.add(a.getQTY());
    }
    return myList;
}
```

Sorry if the question is not clear enough, I am very new to Java programming.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *being used* ? Shouldn't there be something like a `boolean isUsed;` in your `Book` class?

Comment: Apparently, your method is supposed to return the list of audio books that are not used. What is an "unused" audio book. You need to define that first. Once you have that definition, you need to iterate though the audio book, and for each audio book, test if it's unused. If it's unused, then add it to the result list. You don't need any List<Integer>.

Comment: @P. Soutzikevich, yes sorry I forgot to write that down, I will edit it now.

Comment: see @JBNizet 's advice

Comment: @JBNizet: Would this be a correct implementation?

`for(int i = 0; i<myAudioBooks.size(); i++){`
`AudioBook a = myAudioBooks.get(i);`
`if(a.isUsed == true){`
`myList.add(k);`
`}`
`}`

Comment: Yes, but it would be cleaner if you used a foreach loop (`for (AudioBook book : myAudioBooks)`), and if you just used `if (book.isUsed)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking 2 different questions which require 2 different solutions:

Q1: My first question is, how do I check, for each item how many are there and how many are being used?

A1: 
--- Iterate using a classic for each loop ---

```html
public Integer findQTYofUsedBooks(){  // although I would suggest to go for a Long
    Integer qty = 0;
    for( Book book: myAudioBooks ) {    // forEach loop in java
      if(book.isUsed()) {
        qty += book.getQTY();    
      }
    }
    return qty;
}
```

A2: After you will get a bit more advanced you will discover some powerful API's like streams which makes the solution even more trivial:

--- Iterate using streams ---

```html
    public Integer findQTYofUsedBooks(){  
    return myAudioBooks.stream()                   // iterate
                .filter(book -> book.isUsed())     // keep only used books
                .mapToInt(book -> book.getQTY())   // get QTY 
                .sum();                            // sum the QTY
    }
```

Q2: how do I add the not used items in myList?

A1:

```html
public List<Book> findNotUsedBooks(){

    List<Book> notUsedBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for( Book book: myAudioBooks ) {   // same trick as before just this time we add to a list of books
      if( !book.isUsed()) {
        notUsedBooks.add(book);
      }
    }
    
    return notUsedBooks;
}
```

A2: ( with streams )

```html
public List<Book> findNotUsedBooks(){
    return myAudioBooks.stream()
                       .filter( book -> !book.isUsed())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. I just have one more question regarding the very first code that you posted:
the part with `qty += book.getQTY()` doesn't work, because my `getQTY()` method is located in `AudioBook` class. How do I access it?

Comment: The only thing that you need to do is to change the type inside the `for` each loop from `Book` to `AudioBook`. This is how references works in java, a `Book` reference gives you access to: user, name and isUsed; while an `AudioBook` reference gives you access to: name, user, isUsed, totalQty and neededQty.